# Moving my character/camera makes environnement jerky

Tags: unity, 2d, camera, tiles

I'm learning to make a Tilebased game with Unity and for that I use the Zelda alttp assets.
I just have Tiles, a Camera and a moving Character with a rigidbody2D and a CircleCollider.

When the Camera follows the Character, the scene feels Jerky.

Info:

- The Camera uses the 2D Pixel Perfect package.
- The Character is moving via Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() in the `FixedUpdate` Method:

code:

```
void Update()
{
    float yInput;
    float xInput;

    #region yMovement
    if (Input.GetKey(keyMoveTop))
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(keyMoveBot))
        {
            yInput = 0f;
        }
        else yInput = 1f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(keyMoveBot))
    {
        yInput = -1f;
    }
    else yInput = 0f;
    #endregion

    #region xMovement
    if (Input.GetKey(keyMoveLeft))
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(keyMoveRight))
        {
            xInput = 0f;
        }
        else xInput = -1f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(keyMoveRight))
    {
        xInput = 1f;
    }
    else xInput = 0f;
    #endregion

    //Walking
    isWalking = Input.GetKey(keyMoveWalk);
    moveDirection = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(transform.right * xInput + transform.up * yInput, 1f);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + moveDirection * (isWalking ? walkSpeed : runSpeed) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

You can see the problem here:
https://youtu.be/MA2zZPME5X4

Edit: Added all my movement code

Comment: Have you looked at your framerate? Is it 60 fps (or whatever the refresh rate of your monitor is)?

Comment: No I didn't but it would be very weird to not have max fps plying this "game" since it's a gaming computer ^^

Comment: @Foxwarrior Unity shows I have 70 to 80 fps during playmode

Comment: Could it be a rounding problem in your movement code? Like if walkspeed was 0.6 pixels per frame, then it would appear to move 0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1 pixels in a given frame, and look very jerky.
Or maybe it's because you're moving in FixedUpdate but rendering in Update, which aren't synchronized with each other.

Comment: @Foxwarrior I removed the PixelPerfect component to the Camera (so I think there's nothing that rounds values now) the problem is still here :(

Answer (score 1):

Cameras are ***very sensible*** to anything that does not move them perfectly smoothly. The camera should be updated in an Update or LateUpdate. One way to handle cameras is to adjust variables in a FixedUpdate, and to move the camera in the (Late)Update based on the given variables. Moving the player in a FixedUpdate with the camera being parented to will cause flickering.

The reason why is because FixedUpdate does not align with the frame rate. Update and LateUpdate however do, which is why these are the ideal moments to move your camera.

Many people like to attach their cameras to the player, but I'd discourage from doing so. Cameras should have their own, controlled moving patterns unrelated to the arbitrary movements of the player, otherwise you risk all sorts of flickering issues like this including a loss of camera quality in general.

Comment: Things I just tried: I tried using a virtual Camera (with Cinemachine) that follows the player with some damping, same problem. I tried moving the Character in the Update Method, same problem. I even tried just moving the camera but it does the same thing. Maybe is a problem with the code? (I used the same code with all my attemps) I'm lost :(

Comment: @Sharpnel - Alright, then it sounds like a performance issue. Maybe you wrote some horrible code. Often a combination of instantiates, Debug.Log and wild loops. Look into: Unity Editor > Window > Analysis > Profiles (or Ctrl+7). See if there are weird spikes during runtime. If you can't figure it out, activate "Deep Profile." That may slow down everything, but you'll get pinpointed to the exact code part which causes performance issues and also some neat statistics. Alternative tool is to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and test suspicious code parts.

Comment: I've created a new scene and added to it a sprite. I attached the Movement code to the camera (I added a rigidbody2D to the camera) and that's it. The problem is still here ^^ (I have edited this topic and added all my Movement code)

Comment: (weird?) spikes: https://imgur.com/a/0HLr76N

Comment: @Sharpnel - Your code looks fine. Nothing nowhere near problematic is in there. You have to analyze the spikes in the analyzer. It looks like "Rendering" causes it, so it likely has something to do with graphics/GPU. Maybe you use extraordinary large textures, maybe you use some asset that is broken, maybe it's due to the Unity version. Either way, that's a problem *outside* of your camera. The solution for your camera is regardless of that to **never** move it with FixedUpdate, which you still do! (Late)Update aligns with the frame rate, FixedUpdate does not.

Comment: @Sharpnel - A simple solution (solution for the camera, which I recommend you to do so regardless) is to unparent the camera from the player, give it a script, and update its position in an Update() or LateUpdate() method to always be set in a specific offset from the player.

Comment: There are more reasons to make the camera an independent game object with its own movement physics. Good 2d camera handling is more than just sticking to the player. There is a very interesting GDC talk from 2015 which provides a lot of examples of what you can do with camera behavior in a 2d game: [How Cameras in Side-Scrollers Work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdvCO97jOQk). What I find interesting is that there are so many examples of subtle camera controls from the 90s and even the 80s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips guys! Anyway, I have updated my graphic card's drivers, downloaded a newer version of Unity and rebooted my computer and it seems to be fine now. What can I do with this topic since the problem came from something else and I don't even know what solved it? I can't delete it. Thanks for your time again

Comment: @Sharpnel - It's ok, somebody else might stumble upon this who might have issues with their cameras flickering and will find some answers.